# Связь один к одному. Внешний ключ по-разному располагается в таблице

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Здравствуйте. В Visual Studio в проект можно добавить **Модель ADO.NET EDM**, если для работы с Entity Framework используется **Model-First** подход. Или же **Модель ADO.NET EDM** в Visual Studio автоматически появится в проекте, если используется **Database-First** подход.

Так вот мне нужно было для двух сущностей сделать ассоциацию один-к-одному. Например, вот я сделал это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При создании ассоциации между двумя сущностями появляется такое окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь интуитивно всё понятно, как настраивать ассоциацию при создании, за исключением одного момента. В этом окне слева-направо указаны сущности: `Reader` и `BlackList`. Ассоциация имеет имя `ReaderBlackList`. Но, я же могу эти две сущности поменять местами слева-направо и будет так: `BlackList` и `Reader`, имя ассоциации `BlackListReader`.

После создания ассоциации, если зайти в окно свойство, то можно обнаружить следующее свойство: имя набора ассоциаций, которое имеет такое же название:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зачем я на это обращаю ваше внимание? Дело в том, что при формировании SQL-скрипта после создания **Модели ADO.NET EDM** внешний ключ по-разному ведёт себя в этих двух сущностях, то есть, внешний ключ может находиться либо в сущности `Reader`, либо в сущности `BlackList`.

Далее я решил поэкспериментировать с этим. Результат эксперимента приведён ниже (если вдруг кто-то не понял эту картинку, то дополню свой пост об этом):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если обратите внимание, то при одинаковых значениях кратности (1 — 1, например) для двух сущностей, внешние ключи по-разному располагаются в таблицах. И это расположение зависит от имени набора ассоциаций.

**Вопрос: Почему так происходит и есть ли в этом какая-то логика?**

Comment: Если рассматривать `Reader` сущностью, а `BlackList` - таблицей с доп. св-вами для `Reader`, то в тб. `BlackList` `Id` - одновременно должно быть и первичным и внешним ключом. Больше, пожалуй, никаких хитростей в отношении `один-к-одному` нет.